# How to use php-cli.ini?

Tags: php, apache, cron, ini

I am using an open source helpdesk system named iTop. It is possible to insert tickets into it, so that support agents can react on them. With every ticket created the system sends an email notification to the appropriate support agent.

There is as well a function for handling TTO (time to own) and TTR (time to resolve). Here as well the system sends an email. The only difference is that this process must be handeled asynchronously, because sending an email is triggered by the countdown time of TTO and TTR. The iTop system therefore has a `cron.php` file.

Now I tried to create a cron job on my Windows Server to preriodically (every 5 minutes) run a file called `cron.cmd`. This file runs these lines:

```
09   SET PHP_PATH=C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.6.0\php\php.exe
11   SET PHP_INI=C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.6.0\php\php-cli.ini
14   SET CRON_SCRIPT=%~p0cron.php
16   SET PARAMS_FILE=%~p0cron.params
18   "%PHP_PATH%" -c "%PHP_INI%" -f "%CRON_SCRIPT%" -- --param_file="%PARAMS_FILE%" --verbose=1 >> "%~p0log.txt"
```

**The problem is** that I don't find any `php-cli.ini` file in my PHP installation. I therefore believe that I will have to create one for myself. Pointing the `cron.cmd` to the normal php.ini fails.

So now my question is, how to create a `php-cli.ini` file. How would I do that? What do I have to concider?

Comment: No idea about third-party packages like EasyPHP but the official PHP distributions bundles two templates with self-descriptive names: `php.ini-development` and `php.ini-production`. You simply copy the chosen one with explorer and rename it to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

In case of windows, there is no php-cli.ini available. Either you should create copy of php.ini or just pass php.ini path with `-c` option.

Comment: I passed the `php.ini` using `-c`, but the job of the `cron.php` is not done. I know that the cron.php works, because it works, when I access it through the web browser.

Comment: You should check loaded php.ini in browser using `phpinfo()` & then use the same INI when using command line.

Comment: Checked it! It's the same INI in phpinfo() as in my cron.php. Couldn't find any error. Any idea what I could check? The error has to be somewhere.

Comment: please show me output of phpinfo(). Add image in question or upload somewhere.